# American - English

Tags: meaning

Jimmy and I or Jimmy and me.
My aunt was like a second mother to Jimmy and I. My aunt was like a second mother to Jimmy and me.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy and I = we

Jimmy and me = us

So, we change ***Jimmy and I/Jimmy and me*** for ***we/us*** and then evaluate which one fits better in the sentence...

I'd go with *My aunt was like a second mother to Jimmy and me.*

Answer (score 0):

For most sentences, an easy way to figure the answer would be to take the other pronoun out and see which one makes the most sense.